# How do I suggest a tag synonym?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Has this feature disappeared? Or do I need more reputation to suggest a tag synonym?

Comment: What tag are you trying to add a synonym to?

Comment: `word-sense-diambiguation` => `wsd`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Click on the tag you want to suggest a synonym for.  There is link to right of top users and new answers, called 'synonym'.  Click on that.  Example:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/synonyms

The requirements for tag synonyms are listed on each synonym page and are:

*Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.*

Comment: If I want to suggest a 'AAA' synonym with 'BBB', I need to have 5+ score on 'AAA' or 'BBB', or both? And, is there a page I can see how much score I have for each tag?

Comment: Look under tags in your profile.