# Advice about combining tags

Tags: support, tags

Actually, a couple of questions.

- How do I suggest that tags be combined?  For example, it seems to me that iPhone, iOS and iOS4 are all the same tag.  (Sure, iOS4 might be 4-specific questions, but it's  not clear that people use them that way, and 5 is due out soon and, a year from now, it'll be 6, 7, 8...)
- I don't think I have the privilege yet but, regardless, once I do, are there guidelines for when to combine/not-combine tags?  Is it just my personal sense of what makes sense, or are there "community standards" and guidelines about when to/not-to combine?

Thanks!

Comment: Post a list and let the community debate it. Sometimes synonym links will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough reputation within a tag that would become the parent of your proposed tag synonym, then you can [suggest the tag synonym yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86020/how-do-i-suggest-a-tag-synonym).  As far as combining tags, only moderators can do that automatically.  Those with enough privilege can manually retag questions to a new tag if it is deemed appropriate.

Otherwise, simply post a [support](/questions/tagged/support) post here explaining your reasoning and then the community/moderators will come to a decision.