# How to make people use the right tag for Apache-POI?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poi

The bigger part of these questions is about Apache-POI, either the Java or the .Net (NPOI) version. Although the tag description of POI reads `ambiguous/obsolete Please use Apache-POI` all new questions (about Apache-POI) are still tagged with POI.

Is there any mechanism to make people use Apache-POI?

The POI tag itself is ambiguous because it's also used for 'Point Of Interest' (and I think I saw some other meaning too.)

Any suggestions on how to handle this <dramatic>**tag abuse**</dramatic>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could retag the existing [poi](/questions/tagged/poi) questions with whatever disambiguated tags are appropriate, then make [poi](/questions/tagged/poi) a [synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86020/how-do-i-suggest-a-tag-synonym) of [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi).  Removing it will discourage further use.  Anyone who uses it *should* see it change, then update their post to use the correct tags.

Note that [point-of-interest](/questions/tagged/point-of-interest) itself has zero uses, so it really should be created if [poi](/questions/tagged/poi) is being used for that meaning.

Comment: I think I could find myself in the above steps.

Comment: Actually, one can make it a synonym (without merging) first, and then gradually edit the existing questions to point to the right tag.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I wasn't 100% sure which tag to make it a synonym of.

Comment: Of the [last 50 active questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poi?sort=active&pagesize=50), there are maybe 5-7 ones about point-of-interest, the rest is about Apache POI. So this seems to be the right synonym.

Comment: Anything I should do to set this plan in motion?

Comment: @Wivani It would be a big help if you could go through and retag the ones that should be tagged `point-of-interest`.  Once that's done, I can retag the rest in bulk to `apache-poi`, and create the tag synonym so `poi` -> `apache-poi`.

Comment: I'm on it. Will report here once I've finished.

Comment: Forgot that I can't create the point-of-interest tag myself. Can anyone help out?

Comment: @Wivani I made the tag and added it on a few posts.  There are still more that need to be changed before I can do a mass retag. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[poi]+point+of+interest  Thanks.

Comment: There is [one question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5353777/701884) that is about Plone-POI (issue tracker). I removed the POI tag for this one; the remaining questions with tag POI are all about Apache-POI now (double-checked)

Comment: Thanks @Wivani.  I merged all the remaining tags and created the synonym.