# How do I navigate to the tag synonyms page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, navigation

I am trying to figure out how to easily navigate to the following URL from my main SO page:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms
```

I got this URL by editing the one suggested in the post [How do I suggest a tag synonym?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86020/how-do-i-suggest-a-tag-synonym), but I have not been able to go here without just pasting and editing the URL.

I have tried going to the *Tags* tab, and clicking *info*, or *faq*, or clicking *about >>* when a tag the tag is in the right column - but I cannot get back to the page I want (I don't even get to a page with a *Synonyms* tab.

Is this some *hidden feature*, or is there a straight forward way to navigate here that I am totally missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get to it from the tag page (i.e. [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate)), in the info box:

[image: link to synonyms]

(or from the "synonyms" tab if you're already on the "top users"/one of the top answers pages)

There's also a [list of all existing and proposed tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), which is accessible from both the individual tag synonym pages and from the "tag synonyms" link located at the bottom left of the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't seem too *intuitive* (having to click "top users" first) - but knowing where it is sure makes it easy.

Comment: Yeah, the synonym functionality on Stack Exchange could do with a number of improvements, visibility being one of them.